# Empty action attribute on a form with angularJS

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

I'm trying to submit a form the normal way in a AngularJS application but I encounter an issue : it seems that I must specify the action attribute.

According to the HTML specifications (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) :

> If action is the empty string, let action be the document's address of
>   the form document.

But AngularJS refuses to submit the form if the action attribute is not filled.
A work-around I found would be to use action="#" but this is not an acceptable solution since I might use the hash and I don't want it to be rewritten.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue ?

Edit : I don't want to use angular for this form, I just want to submit it the "old" way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js submit form old way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945837/angular-js-submit-form-old-way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the library, you can see that Angular listens to the event `submit` of your forms without action : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b9fa5c5a6781f4e1ec337f27d55c69db491a6555/src/ng/directive/form.js#L331

You can comment this line, it works, but I'm against editing the code of libraries.

Few lines after, you can see that Angular listening to the event `$destroy` enabling to remove the action on this event.

Therefore, to avoid modifying Angular, you can just trigger this event of your form:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#loginForm")).triggerHandler("$destroy")‌​; 
});
```

The reason of this behavior is described few lines above:

> we can't use jq events because if a form is destroyed during submission the default action is not prevented.

And the related issue is: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1238

Comment: Here is the jqLite version of the snippet you posted : angular.element(document).ready(function(){
angular.element(document.querySelector("#loginForm")).triggerHandler("$destroy");
 });

Answer (score 6):

I created a small directive to solve this:

```
.directive('form', ['$location', function($location) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        priority: 999,
        compile: function() {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element, attrs){
                    if (attrs.noaction === '') return;
                    if (attrs.action === undefined || attrs.action === ''){
                        attrs.action = $location.absUrl();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Seems to be good for me. It looks for a form where the action is empty, and sets it to the current url.

Actually, it doesn't set the action - it sets the attr value, so the actual form directive thinks it's got one.

**Update** by @Reimund is good - I have actually had to do the same.

**New Update** - I have added the option to add a `noaction` attribute to the form element; this enables you to return to a "normal" angular situation. Otherwise this directive will submit forms twice if using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-submit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSubmit).

Form

```
<form name="test" action="" ng-submit="submit()">
  What's your name? <input ng-model="name" /><br />
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
<br />
My name is: {{name}}
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.name = $scope.name + ' Doe';
  }
});
```

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rqAwxWmozrzwwj4oAU5k?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Normally I simply make button with ng-click handler.

```
 <button ng-click="Generate()">Submit</button><br>
```